# Calculate how many times a specific word appears in one column within a week that fall within

Tags: excel

I hope I am wording this correctly.

I need to calculate how many times a word appears in a column next to a number which can range from 1- 52. example (numbers in column B, words in column C)

```
1   Apples
1   Banana
1   Apples
2   Apples
2   Banana
2   Apples
2   Banana
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,1,C:C,"Apples")`

Replace the `1` with your Number to search, and `"Apples"` with your Word to search.

Creating a pivot table would also get you what you want:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  so easy, i was staring at it for too long, i think.